# Tricky proof in Natural Deduction [¬∀x∃y¬Rxy ⊢ ∃x∀yRxy]-help appreciated

Tags: predicate-logic, first-order-logic, natural-deduction

As it says in the title, I'm trying to prove the statement ¬∀x∃y¬Rxy ⊢ ∃x∀yRxy in the system of Natural Deduction, with basic rules for negation intro and elimination, and existential or universal quantifier intro and elim.

I can use the premiss to create a contradiction, so the penultimate line might be:

¬∀x∃y¬Rxy      ∀x∃y¬Rxy

```
     ∃x∀yRxy
```

But how do I derive the assumption ∀x∃y¬Rxy? It might be:

```
               ¬Rab 
             ∃y¬Ray              
           ∀x∃y¬Rxy
```

So ¬Rab must be derived from some assumption Rab that leads to contradiction-that's where I'm stuck! Any help appreciated-this is not my homework or anything, it just bugs me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need :

1) $¬∀x∃y¬Rxy$ --- premise

2) $¬∃x∀yRxy$ --- assumption [a] : the assumption to be contradicted, deriving (by *Double Negation*) the sought conclusion : $∃x∀yRxy$

3) $∀yRxy$ --- assumption [b] : in order to derive a contradiction with 2) to conclude, by $¬$-intro, with : $¬∀yRxy$, discharging [b].

Now we need a "detour", in order to derive from $¬∀yRxy$ the classically equivalent : $∃y¬Rxy$.

Having derived $∃y¬Rxy$, we can "generalize" it to  $∀x∃y¬Rxy$. We can do it, because neither in the premise nor into assumption [a] $x$ is *free*.

Thus, $∀x∃y¬Rxy$ contradicts the *premise* 1) and we can conclude by *Double Negation* again with :

> $∃x∀yRxy$,

discharging [a].

Comment: Thanks Mauro, I've got it now! I didn't use the right assumption, that got me into trouble.

Answer (score 1):

$\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline #2\end{array}}$

The thing about natural deduction is that if something *is* provable, you can often reverse engineer the proof by deciding what needs to be, and may be, introduced or eliminated, step by step.

Okay, so our goal is to prove that a conditional statement is a theorem (that it holds with  no premises).
$$\fitch{}{~~\vdots\\\neg\forall x\exists y~\neg Rxy\to\exists x\forall y~Rxy}$$

Well, clearly, to derive a conditional statement we need a conditional proof.

$$\fitch{}{\fitch{\neg\forall x\exists y~\lnot Rxy}{~~\vdots\\\exists x\forall y~Rxy}\\\neg\forall x\exists y~\neg Rxy\to\exists x\forall y~Rxy}$$

We have nothing available to construct a witnesses, so to derive *this* existential statement, we need to show that it cannot not hold (ie: a proof by contradiction). And obviously the thing we will be contradicting is that assumption. So we need a universal introduction proof.

$$\fitch{}{\fitch{\neg\forall x\exists y~\lnot Rxy}{\fitch{\neg\exists x\forall y~Rxy }{\fitch{[a]}{~~\vdots\\\exists y~\neg Ray}\\\forall x\exists y~\neg Rxy\\\bot}\\\neg\neg\exists x\forall y~Rxy\\\exists x\forall y~Rxy}\\\neg\forall x\exists y~\neg Rxy\to\exists x\forall y~Rxy}$$

Again, to prove this existential statement we need a proof by contradiction, this time aiming to contradict the second assumption.

$$\fitch{}{\fitch{\neg\forall x\exists y~\lnot Rxy}{\fitch{\neg\exists x\forall y~Rxy }{\fitch{[a]}{\fitch{\neg\exists y~\neg Ray}{~\vdots\\\exists x\forall y~Rxy\\\bot}\\\neg\neg\exists y~\neg Ray\\\exists y~\neg Ray}\\\forall x\exists y~\neg Rxy\\\bot}\\\neg\neg\exists x\forall y~Rxy\\\exists x\forall y~Rxy}\\\neg\forall x\exists y~\neg Rxy\to\exists x\forall y~Rxy}$$

Okay, we finally have something that might act as a witness for this existential statement, that is *if* we can derive $\forall y~Ray$, so attempting a universal proof is indicated.

$$\fitch{}{\fitch{\neg\forall x\exists y~\lnot Rxy}{\fitch{\neg\exists x\forall y~Rxy }{\fitch{[a]}{\fitch{\neg\exists y~\neg Ray}{\fitch{[b]}{~~\vdots\\Rab}\\\forall y~Ray\\\exists x\forall y~Rxy\\\bot}\\\neg\neg\exists y~\neg Ray\\\exists y~\neg Ray}\\\forall x\exists y~\neg Rxy\\\bot}\\\neg\neg\exists x\forall y~Rxy\\\exists x\forall y~Rxy}\\\neg\forall x\exists y~\neg Rxy\to\exists x\forall y~Rxy}$$

Now to derive this statement ($Rab$) from the assumptions, it is time to do a proof by contradiction for the assumption of $\neg\exists y~\neg Ray$.   Well, since the required existential may immediately be introduced from the assumption, we are done.

$$\fitch{}{\fitch{\neg\forall x\exists y~\lnot Rxy}{\fitch{\neg\exists x\forall y~Rxy }{\fitch{[a]}{\fitch{\neg\exists y~\neg Ray}{\fitch{[b]}{\fitch{\neg Rab}{\exists y~\neg Ray\\\bot}\\\neg\neg Rab\\Rab}\\\forall y~Ray\\\exists x\forall y~Rxy\\\bot}\\\neg\neg\exists y~\neg Ray\\\exists y~\neg Ray}\\\forall x\exists y~\neg Rxy\\\bot}\\\neg\neg\exists x\forall y~Rxy\\\exists x\forall y~Rxy}\\\neg\forall x\exists y~\neg Rxy\to\exists x\forall y~Rxy}$$

Okay, aside from numbering the lines and adding justifications, we are done.

$\blacksquare$